# How can I move the Exit, Maximize, Minimize buttons to the left in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, window-buttons, window-decoration

I want to move exit, maximize, and minimize button to the left like I can do in Ubuntu 11.10. How to do it?

Comment: What version KDE are yo using?

Comment: I guess I am using v5.7. Not sure how to check the version.

Comment: @fossfreedom Yep. Same question. Please delete this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is done in **Window Decorations** KDE Control Module.

Click **Configure Buttons...**, check **Use custom titlebar button positions** and rearrange everything as you like.

[image: Buttons]

Answer (score 4):

KDE/Plasma5 can set button placement by going to `Application Style` -> `Window Decoration` and then simply dragging the close, max and min buttons in the title bar where ever you want them.

[image]

Comment: The buttons are little difficult to move but this is the answer for modern Plasma. Thank you.

Comment: @BlackBlock, this should be the selected answer for current version of Plasma.