# How to move window controls to the left in KDE?

Tags: kde, window-buttons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I move the Exit, Maximize, Minimize buttons to the left in Kubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94355/how-can-i-move-the-exit-maximize-minimize-buttons-to-the-left-in-kubuntu)

Months of using Unity has trained me to look for window controls on the left topside of the windows. Unfortunately, KDE desktop puts the window controls on the right side and I don't like it there. Is it possible to move it to the left side?